# How to vibrate with sound

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add sound while vibration.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Get Ready Bus is Near",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(2000);
}
```

Vibration Applied successfully, but how to add sound while phone vibrate?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that using `MediaPlayer`.

Firstly, Create an instance of `MediaPlayer` class:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Then, set the source file, in order to this, firstly place the audio file in `res/raw` folder of your `Project` directory, then use this code:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://{package name}/res/raw/{audio file name}");
```

Then play that file using this code:

```
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Keep in mind that you have to put this code in `try | catch` block.

Now your whole code will be this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"Get Ready Bus is Near",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Initializing instance of Vibrator.
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // Initializing instance of MediaPlayer.
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    // Starting Vibration
    v.vibrate(2000);

    try {
        // Setting the source of audio file.
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://{package name}/res/raw/{audio file name}");  // Fill the information accordingly.
        mediaPlayer.prepare();

        // playing audio.
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```